# Is there an antonym for "nice-to-have"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, antonyms

Let's suppose that while looking for a new car, I end up with a list of requirements that I would like my new car to satisfy. I proceed to put these requirements into one of the following categories:

- Must-haves
- Nice-to-haves
- *"Not-so-nice-to-haves"*
- Deal breakers

Is there a more concise and/or idiomatic word or phrase for *"not-so-nice-to-haves"*?

Comment: What's the point of having this category and "dealbreakers" in the first place? If "manual drive" is a dealbreaker, then "automatic drive" is a must have.

Comment: You haven't said what you're looking for in an antonym. Do you mean something in one of the categories of *unnecessary*, *disliked*, or *hated*? Or a different category? When you say *not nice to have* what exactly are you trying to express? Please provide a sample sentence that makes the meaning clear.

Answer (score 2):

drawback

> : an objectionable feature : DISADVANTAGE
>   The plan's only drawback is its cost.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drawback

Also demerit, disadvantage, inconvenience, shortcoming, stumbling block, detriment, nuisance

Answer (score 1):

[White elephant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/white%20elephant)

In particular this sense:

> an object no longer of value to its owner but of value to others

If it's a feature designed into a car, it's of value to the manufacturer and other potential buyers, irrespective of how you value it.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to consider the old marketing distinction between a **feature** and a **benefit**. The principle is that customers but something because it brings them benefits, but that designers of products tend to be more interested in features, irrespective of whether anyone else regards them as a benefit.

So I would interpret your "not so nice to haves" as features that you  personally see no benefit in. A 'deal breaker', on the other hand, is just a plain old disadvantage.

I therefore propose the phrase "useless features".

Comment: It used to be said that Microsoft products never had bugs, only features as in "Crashing regularly is a feature of Windows 95"

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, as in the irregular verb: my software has features, your software has bugs, his software doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The "*Not-so-nice-to-haves*" can be termed ***niggles*** - just minor annoyances and not big enough to be deal-breakers.

ODO:

> **[niggle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/niggle)**
>   *NOUN*
>   **A trivial** criticism, discomfort, or **annoyance**.
>
> ‘However, apart from these niggles, the Monster is great fun to ride
>   and is the perfect first big bike’.’